# Stacking columns one below other when the column names are same

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge data set in a pandas data frame. It looks something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[31,14,13,11],[115,613,1313,1]], columns=['c1','c1','c2','c2'])
```

Here first two columns have same name. So they should be concatenated into a single column so the the values are one below another. so the dataframe should look something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[31,13],[115,1313],[2,4],[14,11],[613,1]], columns=['c1','c2'])
```

Note: My orignal dataframe has many column so I cannot used simple concat function to stack the columns. Also I tried using stack function, apart from concat function. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

use `groupby` + `cumcount` to create a `pd.MultiIndex`.  Reassign `column` with new `pd.MultiIndex` and `stack`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,2,3,4],[31,14,13,11],[115,613,1313,1]],
    columns=['c1','c1','c2','c2'])   


df1 = df.copy()
df1.columns = [df.columns, df.columns.to_series().groupby(level=0).cumcount()]
print(df1.stack().reset_index(drop=True))

    c1    c2
0    1     3
1    2     4
2   31    13
3   14    11
4  115  1313
5  613     1
```

Or with a bit of creativity, in one line

```
df.T.set_index(
    df.T.groupby([df.columns]).cumcount(),
    append=True
).unstack().T.reset_index(drop=True)

    c1    c2
0    1     3
1    2     4
2   31    13
3   14    11
4  115  1313
5  613     1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I want my new data frame to be populated first with elements of first c1 and then go to second c1. So column c1 should have elements in this order: 1,31,115,2,14,613.

Answer (score 0):

You could melt the dataframe, then count entries within each column to use as index for the new dataframe and then unstack it back like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,2,3,4],[31,14,13,11],[115,613,1313,1]],
    columns=['c1','c1','c2','c2']) 

df1 = (pd.melt(df,var_name='column')
         .assign(n = lambda x: x.groupby('column').cumcount())
         .set_index(['n','column'])
         .unstack())
df1.columns=df1.columns.get_level_values(1)
print(df1)
```

Which produces

```
column   c1    c2
n                
0         1     3
1        31    13
2       115  1313
3         2     4
4        14    11
5       613     1
```